Share info not retrieved from current page OG tags
We are trying to share job ads on LinkedIn but it only gets title and image from our start page. When we share the same ad on Facebook it looks as expected. I have also checked that our URL is not disallowed in robots.txt which I heard could be a problem.
Can anyone see what is the problem in the following ad?
https://www.jobbet.se/annonser/alma-assistans/kund--och-personalansvarig-inom-personlig-ass/clvurlb7000w0vm64t3ut1vux


Ok, I managed to solve this. First I thought it was a missing canonical URL that was the reason but it was the meta og:url that was wrong. Since LinkedIn did not pick the other OG meta tags from the ad page I did not even consider to check the og:url value at first.
